# Testing Highcharts (JS charting library) with Cucumber

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, highcharts

I have an application in which we help our clients visualize data via graphs rendered with [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). The data processing and visualization is the primary value our application provides, in other words its important and should be tested.

I am using cucumber to write integration tests for the application, I would like to include some basic tests of our highcharts implementation. I am especially keen to test that the correct data is being plotted as well as that custom ajax interactions are working correctly. An example feature might look something like this:

```
Feature: Plot Related Alarm Data
  As an project owner
  I want to see antecedent data plotted around the time of the alarm
  So that I can diagnose the issue and save gobs of money.

  Background:
    Given a bunch of stuff is set up
    And I am logged in
    # ...

  Scenario: Alarm data is plotted
    Given I have an alarm
    # ...
    When I visit the alarm show page
    Then I should see 5 days of data in my graph

  Scenario: Alarm data is clicked
    Given # ...
    When # ...
    And I click on a data point
    Then I should be on the data page
```

Any experience testing things like this and which tool Selenium, Watir, etc was used would be appreciated.

Comment: For the plotted data, I would say that your test boundary is the data that is passed to Highchart; there's no point in testing Highchart's rendering/graphing.

Answer (score 2):

A strategy that I've used:

1. render the data in an HTML table
2. generate the chart in JavaScript
   using the data from that table (e.g. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed)
3. use Cucumber just to
   verify that the table contains the
   expected data using [table diffs via tableish](https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/multiline-step-arguments)